# Mix a bag of 25KG self-leveling concrete with 6L of water?

Tags: water, concrete, flooring

**I bought a 24L bucket to fit the mix of 25KG of [self-leveling concrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-leveling_concrete) (Thomsit DD+) and 6L of water.** Now, visually inspecting the thing, I can't really tell if it's large enough to handle the amount. It seems to be but not totally sure.

*Can anyone tell me if the volume fits or should I aim for a larger bucket?* I'd rather not drop the bag of cement dust in the bucket and realize it's not large enough and then have to move it around.

*UPDATE: [This is the procedure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ua76YdbwO9M). And their bucket size is close to mine.*

Comment: Just a note as @ecnewral mentioned put most of the water in first but do not add all at 1 time save back at least 1/2 L. After fully mixed if the mix ts stiff add 1/4L mix then test again you may need all the water but where I live I rarely need all the water listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lacking a specific brand from your question, I went and looked at

http://www.screwfix.com/p/mapei-ultraplan-self-levelling-compound-grey-25kg/4959f

Which states that it will cover (mixed) 6 square meters at 3mm thick.

I make that 100cm x 600 cm x 0.3 cm or 18,000 cubic centimeters. Last I checked, 1000 CCs was a liter, so you have 6 liters of free space.

Comment: This matches what I managed to find myself. **Thanks for confirming!**

Comment: OK, I see you've already accepted this answer. I'm afraid you don't appreciate just how difficult it will be to mix the cement in such a confined space, but that's OK -- live and learn!

Comment: @DaveTweed I added a video to the post. Check it out.

Comment: Starting with the water in the bucket is easier - less prone to dry pockets in the lower corners - so is using a mixing paddle for a drill (more or less a heavy-duty paint mixer) - not essential, but helpful if you have it.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Got those. Only dilemma was volume.

Answer (score 0):

That bucket is far too small. Normally, you want to get a "concrete mixing tub" (e.g., at [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Building-Materials-Concrete-Cement-Masonry-Concrete-Tools-Concrete-Mixing-Tubs-Pans/N-5yc1vZaq89)), which is broad enough to allow you to mix the water and the powder thoroughly. I usually use a garden hoe to do the mixing, which allows you to do it standing up. Also, the tub is very smooth on the bottom, which means that it's relatively easy to drag around, even when it's full of material.

Add the water gradually and mix thoroughly after each addition -- the point at which it becomes too soupy happens very quickly, and you want to avoid having too much water in the mix.

Comment: The bag comes with clear instructions to be mixed with only 6L of water. It's a special and quite expensive type of [self-leveling cement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-leveling_concrete).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. There is still some variation in the amount of water required based on things like the humidity of the air, etc.